# OOAD vs Design Patterns -confused

Tags: design-patterns, ooad

I picked up two HEAD first books, OOAD and Design Patterns. I am very confused when I started reading the Design Patterns.
Here are my basic doubts:

1. Is design pattern applicable only to Object oriented Designs? To me it appears that DP can be applied only in OOAD
2. Is Design patterns a part of (a set of tools to use in)  OO design? Specifically what I am trying to ask is, is OOAD the bigger objective and Design patterns help in achieving the objective

After reading the first 4 or 5 patterns it looks like if some body were a good OO Designer, he would have automatically designed using these patterns.

I am really very confused

Answer (score 1):

Patterns, as reusable solutions for problems, can be found in many fields. The idea of using a pattern language to communicate these solutions originates from the field of architecture (see [A Pattern Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pattern_Language)), but has later been applied successfully to software engineering. Even within the field of software engineering patterns exist on different levels, for example [implementation patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/implementation-patterns) and [architectural patterns for enterprise applications](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/).

The title of the seminal book which popularized the notion of software design patterns, [Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29), *does* suggest that the patterns described applies only to object oriented designs (which i think was not the intention of the authors). Some of the creational patterns deal specifically with objects, but almost all other patterns can be implemented in any non object oriented language. For examples in C, see [state pattern](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%202,%20STATE.pdf), [strategy pattern](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%203,%20STRATEGY.pdf) and [observer pattern](http://www.adampetersen.se/Patterns%20in%20C%204,%20OBSERVER.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Design pattern are reusable solutions to problems - the original design patterns book itself very clearly states that they are not specific to any one language or paradigm.

For example - there are even design pattern book for SQL - a declarative language that is very much outside of OOP.

Design patterns tend to be higher level design than one class - they tend to be a number of related classes that together achieve a certain design objective. As such (and as reusable solutions), they are definitely a good tool to have - the value gained from them is less in creating designs with them in mind (patterns should *emerge* from code, not coded to), but with their names - they facilitate communication. If you are talking to someone about a singleton or facade, if they are familiar with design patterns, they will have a good idea of what you are talking about and the design and its goals.

Answer (score 0):

From what my understanding is ,Design pattern is not confined to only object oriented systems .If we notice the words ,Design and Patterns serve different purposes .Pattern is a repeatable activity ,which is coupled to a context and when you apply this theory to designing activity it becomes Design Pattern .Its a tested design solution in a certain context.
OOAD has a bigger umbrella then design patterns ,design patterns are like words in the dictionary whereas OOAD serve as alphabets ,which you use to create words.
OOAD theory has been utilized to create those design patterns .